# Can I switch a pulse solenoid from the onboard 5V/3.3V power source?

Tags: esp8266

I have two pulse solenoids.  One is 6V...

http://www.ebay.com.au/itm/282002733837?_trksid=p2057872.m2749.l2649&ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT

and the other is 3.6V...

http://www.ebay.com.au/itm/131989042565?_trksid=p2057872.m2749.l2649&ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT

I have a Wemos R2 Mini with an `ESP8266` chip on it, and I'm running the switching operation through a H Bridge motor shield (which handily switches the polarity of the electricity for a short time, which opens/shuts the solenoid).

I want to run this thing off a smallish battery pack that will supply 5V to the WeMos. I have three questions:

1) Can I send a 3.6V solenoid a 60ms pulse to open/shut it from a 5V power source without burning out the coil or causing any other damage?

2) Is 3.3V too low to power a 3.6V solenoid?

3) Do pulse solenoids still generate back EMF?

I don't know a lot about solenoids or electromagnetic fields so, sorry if my questions are noobish.

Comment: They seem more concerned with how beautiful it is than providing a datasheet with real information in it. You buy lemons, expect to make lemonade, not a cream cake.

Comment: @Majenko to be fair, it is quite beautiful :D.  I know there is no datasheet/no nothing but for $8 I was happy to give it a crack.  The weird thing is that the design of both solenoids is very solid, and they tested as working when I gave them a go. But yeah, no datasheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) Can I send a 3.6V solenoid a 60ms pulse to open/shut it from a 5V
>   power source without burning out the coil or causing any other damage?

No. If it's 3.6V then you need 3.6V - 5V will most likely make it smoke. Use a regulator (preferably a buck one, since it is apparently 500mA) to power your H-bridge.

> 2) Is 3.3V too low to power a 3.6V solenoid?

Maybe, maybe not. It may be that 3.6V is the absolute maximum and may switch from 3V to 3.6V.

> 3) Do pulse solenoids still generate back EMF?

Normally, yes, since they are just a coil like any other inductive load. Your H-bridge should deal with that though if designed right.

To get any meaningful answers you will need a datasheet. Buying such things from eBay is never a good idea unless you have used it before and know what it is, what its specifications are, and how you use it, or they provide a link to a datasheet. Without a datasheet most questions will be answered with a "maybe".